# Any difference between capital and lowercase XML / RDF tag names?

Tags: xml, firefox, rdf, capitalization

I noticed that the `install.rdf` files of firefox extensions have some capitalized tag names i.e. `<Description>`.

Will it make any difference if it was lowercased i.e. `<description>`?

The files are xml so I don't see the problem but just wondering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Xml elements are case sensitive, and that it's just rdf:Description. So, yes, a well behaved program will fail if it can't find the information it needs.

[This page](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Install.rdf) states that you need to supply a valid install.rdf in your package, so my guess is that installation of the component will fail at some time if it can't find the minimal set of information.

Comment: Good answer! I'll select as best in a few minutes.